# IIS and Crystal Report

Tags: iis-7, crystalreports

A person I know has IIS 7.5 on Win 2008 R2. He has a problematic Crystal Reports aspx page hosted in IIS. (Call this page: P1.)

There are many app pools in IIS.

Suppose some time has passed. During this time users use various web pages.
P1 is served by a particular app pool. (Call this pool1.)
When users use P1, it just says: load report failed. (Other aspx pages served by pool1 can be accessed normally.)

If he recycles pool1, P1 may work again.
If it doesn't work, he can try restart site or server.

He doesn't know if this is Crystal Reports problem or IIS problem.

How can he pinpoint whose problem it is?

Answer (score 0):

you have to check two things

1. use proper version of crystal reports viewer and crystal reports framework. crystal report does not show the actual error codes and it either shows errors like page not loading, export failed etc.
2. check whether application development features in IIS is configured correctly